Signal excision of known modulation type using costas loop for carrier recovery? or is there a better approach?
I am trying to excise a modulated signal (selectively remove it as best possible). could be BPSK, QPSK ect but the modulation type is known on the receiver. I have been trying a combination of lowpass filter isolate the signal and costas loop to recover the carrier symbols then subtracting that from the result from the original spectrum with some success for BPSK with the signal suppressed but some distortion from the excision location in the PSD. Is there a better way or is this approach sound? Perhaps should I go further trying to demodulate to recover symbols more selectively (try to get just the BPSK part of the spectrum)?

What is your SNR condition for doing this? Is this an isolated signal with strong SNR in the presence of noise or are you trying to do multi-user detection where you have different signals that occupy the same bandwidth?

"isolated signal with strong SNR in the presence of noise" - yes isolated modulated signal of a known modulation type with a good SNR

The OP has clarified in the comments that the objective is to isolate a single modulated signal that has a high SNR. In this case a high cancellation ratio can be achieved with care to match the waveform as we would expect it to appear at the particular location in the receiver where the cancellation is to take place (such as before or after the matched filter for example). The waveform as received will typically have amplitude, phase, time and frequency offsets which the receiver will correct as well as channel distortions (multipath) that an equalizer can correct— this means with a high SNR all of these defects can be easily determined and corrected for with proper receiver design. This also means that the waveform as it would appear at any position in the receiver can also be recreated for optimum cancellation (at that location) by reintroducing these offsets and errors as needed (as long as the necessary delay is tolerable). If any of these offsets are not considered, then the resulting cancellation will be deficient due to those factors.
That said, achieving a satisfactory cancellation in a practical realistic receiver situation can be done using the skills to measure all of these offsets and equalizations mentioned and recreating a waveform from the demodulated symbols to match the waveform as it would appear where the cancellation is to take place: matching in sampling rate, time offset, amplitude, phase and frequency offset. The correlation coefficient and an understanding of fractional delay filters and channel equalizers would be really helpful toward this goal.
